# kafka connector for all tables in database

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I'm starting in debezium and kafka because of work and I'm trying to stream changes from a Mysql database. I followed [this debezium tutorial](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/tutorial.html) and I created a connector for a new table inside a new database that works great! But when I try to stream changes from a whole database, in the watcher container logs I can see all "Contents of topic dbserver3", but no changes are being detected.

This is the config for the connector I'm talking about:

```
{
  "name": "general-connector",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "database.hostname": "mysql",
    "database.port": "3306",
    "database.user": "debezium",
    "database.password": "dbz",
    "database.server.id": "184054",
    "topic.prefix": "dbserver3",
    "schema.history.internal.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",
    "schema.history.internal.kafka.topic": "schema-changes"
  }
}
```

I read from [the docs](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/debezium-mysql-source/current/mysql_source_connector_config.html#required-parameters) that if I don't set the **table.include.list or the database.include.list,** it will take all the tables and databases. I might be wrong, cause it wont work for me.

This works tho (database dbtest, table table_test)

```
{
  "name": "test-connector",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "database.hostname": "mysql",
    "database.port": "3306",
    "database.user": "debezium",
    "database.password": "dbz",
    "database.server.id": "184054",
    "topic.prefix": "dbserver2",
    "database.include.list": "dbtest",
    "schema.history.internal.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",
    "schema.history.internal.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.dbtest"
  }
}
```

Is it recommended to have a connector for all databases? Either way I'd like to know why my connector isn't working, thx in advance!

Comment: btw this is how i was running the docker container: `docker run -d --rm --name watcher3 --link zookeeper:zookeeper --link kafka:kafka quay.io/debezium/kafka:2.4 watch-topic -a -k dbserver3`